# jQuery UI: Auto size and auto center

Tags: jquery-ui

Right now, I have a website that someone made for me, and unfortunately, I'm stuck.  I understand a little, but remain to be a total novice.  I have pictures I want for the pop-up, but whenever I set the height and width to 'auto', the box locates to the bottom of the page?

I need it to auto center on resize as well if possible.

Please help me recreate my code, anyone?  Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function openDialog(url) {
        $("<div class='popupDialog'></div>").load(url)
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                closeOnEscape: true,
                height: '1012',
                modal: true,
                position: ['center', 'center'],
                title: 'About Ricky',
                width: 690
            }).bind('dialogclose', function() {
                jdialog.dialog('destroy');
            });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem you are having is that when the dialog opens it is empty and the position is calculated. Then you load the content and it does not automatically recalculate the new center position. You need to do this yourself in the onComplete event handler. See below, I have also put in some nice loading text :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function openDialog(url) {
        $("<div class='popupDialog'>Loading...</div>")
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                closeOnEscape: true,
                height: '1012',
                modal: true,
                position: ['center', 'center'],
                title: 'About Ricky',
                width: 690
            }).bind('dialogclose', function() {
                jdialog.dialog('destroy');
            }).load(url, function() {
                $(this).dialog("option", "position", ['center', 'center'] );
            });
    }

    $(window).resize(function() {
        $(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("option", "position", ['center', 'center']);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Dean!  I have no idea what you're talking about, but it worked perfectly. (:

Comment: Can you please also help me add a line for auto center when the browser resizes?

Comment: Updated my answer to include browser resize centering.

Comment: You specified a fixed width and height when initializing the dialog, so you don't really need to do your positioning in the callback of your `load()`...